# No bean named 'myUserDetailsService' is defined Spring Security with hibernate and Spring MVC

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc, authentication, spring-security

I am following [this tutorial](http://www.mkyong.com/spring-security/spring-security-hibernate-xml-example/) but i need to make querys without the hbm.xml files and instead use dao and service layers. I have already generated models for both users and user_roles tables using hibernate. I also created the dao's and service layers.

The problem is i get an error that says No bean named 'myUserDetailsService' is defined. I know i have to create a bean but i can't figure out how to do it.

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'myUserDetailsService' is defined
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanDefinition(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:641)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getMergedLocalBeanDefinition(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1159)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:282)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:328)
    ... 93 more
```

I have uploaded the full project to github. Any help/ advice is apreciated.

https://github.com/kunal7L/Spring-MVC-Security-Hibernate

My beans:

```
 <bean id="userDao" class="com.mkyong.users.dao.UserDaoImpl">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="hibernate4AnnotatedSessionFactory" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="userService" class="com.mkyong.users.service.UserServiceImpl">
        <property name="userDao" ref="userDao"></property>
    </bean>

<!--    <bean id="myUserDetailsService" class="com.mkyong.users.service.MyUserDetailsService"> -->
<!--        <property name="userDao" ref="userDao" /> -->
<!--    </bean> -->
```

Full MyUserDetailsService Class:

public class MyUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

```
private UserService userservice;

@Override
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(final String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {

    // Programmatic transaction management
    /*
    return transactionTemplate.execute(new TransactionCallback<UserDetails>() {

        public UserDetails doInTransaction(TransactionStatus status) {
            com.mkyong.users.model.User user = userDao.findByUserName(username);
            List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = buildUserAuthority(user.getUserRole());

            return buildUserForAuthentication(user, authorities);
        }

    });*/

    Users user = userservice.findByUserName(username);
    List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = buildUserAuthority(user.getUserRoleses());

    return buildUserForAuthentication(user, authorities);


}

// Converts com.mkyong.users.model.User user to
// org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User
private User buildUserForAuthentication(Users user, List<GrantedAuthority> authorities) {
    return new User(user.getUsername(), user.getPassword(), user.isEnabled(), true, true, true, authorities);
}

private List<GrantedAuthority> buildUserAuthority(Set<UserRoles> userRoles) {

    Set<GrantedAuthority> setAuths = new HashSet<GrantedAuthority>();

    // Build user's authorities
    for (UserRoles userRole : userRoles) {
        setAuths.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(userRole.getRole()));
    }

    List<GrantedAuthority> Result = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>(setAuths);

    return Result;
}
```

}

Comment: Do not link to third-party sites. Edit your post to include the relevant code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by understanding Hoàng Long's logic. I knew i was missing a bean but i just didn't know what to reference inside it. So i googled it and found out that MyUserDetailsService implements on UserDetailsService which is a part of Spring Security. So the only thing left to do was to add the bean with no property at all.

```
<bean id="myUserDetailsService" class="com.mkyong.users.service.MyUserDetailsService" >

    </bean>
```

Answer (score 2):

The error is very clear:

> No bean named 'myUserDetailsService' is defined

In your file spring-security.xml, you have referred to a bean named myUserDetailsService:

```
<authentication-manager>
    <authentication-provider user-service-ref="myUserDetailsService" >
        <password-encoder hash="bcrypt" />    
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>
```

However, you have commented out the part which define that service in spring-database.xml

```
<!--    <bean id="myUserDetailsService" class="com.mkyong.users.service.MyUserDetailsService"> -->
<!--        <property name="userDao" ref="userDao" /> -->
<!--    </bean> -->
```

That's why the error happens

Comment: I left it commented because i don't know what should i put in property name or ref. I will edit the question with the full class code.

Comment: @Kunal: I don't really understand your question. I will try to guess. ref = "userDao", it means that you must define somewhere a bean named "userDao" too. And somewhere here means several lines above in the same file: you also comment out the code which define it (<!--  <bean id="userDao" class="com.mkyong.users.dao.UserDaoImpl"> -->
<!--   <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" /> -->
<!--  </bean> -->).

Comment: In short, the configuration wants to say: authentication-manager use myUserDetailsService (implemented by com.mkyong.users.service.MyUserDetailsService), which in turn use userDao (com.mkyong.users.dao.UserDaoImpl), which in turn use sessionFactory = hibernate4AnnotatedSessionFactory). Think about them as a tree where each node depends on several others. You need to define them all for the application to work

Comment: Thanks for all of your help. I got to know the answer by understanding your logic. I will post the answer that is quite simple.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you have issue with you Dao object, i am not sure how you set up but if you use annotation then you must configure you persistance.xml and put it in the META-INF folder, and you need to make the application context know about it this link will help you to understand your issue better 
http://www.journaldev.com/3531/spring-mvc-hibernate-mysql-integration-crud-example-tutorial 
just look for the Hibernate datasource configuration and how to use it in your Dao layer.

```
<beans:bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
        destroy-method="close">
        <beans:property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <beans:property name="url"
            value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/TestDB" />
        <beans:property name="username" value="pankaj" />
        <beans:property name="password" value="pankaj123" />
    </beans:bean>
```

Comment: I have followed that tutorial and worked successfully with it but i need to implement a user login component which is why i had to use spring security. but instead of using .hbm.xml files i needed to use service layer just like in the link you sent.